# Prove that $e^{\sum 1/p_k^2} > \pi/2$

Tags: inequality

The $k$th prime is $p_k.$ Prove (if inclined, and without a machine) that

$$\exp\left({\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{p_k^2}}\right) > \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: Where is this question from?  Knowing the source can hint at the method of solution.  My first guess at a solution would be to rewrite the left hand side of the equation as an infinite product and then to compare the terms of the product to the Wallis formula for $\pi/2$, perhaps using $e^x>1+x$, but I can't say for sure that this idea pans out.

Comment: @Aaron: I did the calculation and noticed I could not prove it. A quick search here did not turn it up. It seems familiar but I do not recall seeing it here. It's not a textbook sort of inequality.

Comment: This can be verified by machine by summing the primes up to 250, but is there any reason to think that there should be a proof "by hand"? *i.e.*, what makes this inequality different than putting $1.5717$ on the right-hand-side (which would also be a true inequality, and tighter)?

Comment: @Aaron's suggestion isn't quite good enough.  It gives: $\exp\left( \sum_p \frac1{p^2}\right) = \prod_p \exp\left( \frac1{p^2}\right) > \prod_p \left( 1 + \frac1{p^2} \right) = \prod_p \left( \left(1 - \frac1{p^4}\right)\sum_n \frac1{p^{2n}}\right) = \left( \prod_p \sum_n \frac1{p^{2n}} \right) \prod_p \left(1 - \frac1{p^4} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}6 \prod_p \left( \sum_n \frac1{p^{4n}} \right)^{-1} = \frac{\pi^2}6 \frac{90}{\pi^4} = \frac{15}{\pi^2} $, which is too low by about 0.05.  Maybe using $\exp(x) > (1+\frac x N)^N$ for all $N$?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Using exact value of $\exp{\frac{1}{p^2}}$ for p=2,3,5 then we can fix the gap.

Comment: The LHS is approximately $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6 > \pi/2$, since $\pi > 3$.  This is not quite a proof since I don't know how good the approximation is (in particular, I believe that it is actually the less favorable inequality).

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Taking asatzhh's suggestion into account it seems that the problem is essentially solved. Do you mind writing up an answer with some explanation for the steps?

Comment: @RyanReich Actually $\exp(\sum\frac{1}{p^2})=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-0.073\dots=\frac{\pi}{2}+0.001\dots$. So your estimate seems doesn't work.

Comment: @asatzhh I don't understand your objection; the exponential is larger than $\pi/2$, as claimed.  And it is smaller than $\pi/6$, as I observed was probably true.  So everything I said was right, including the naive inequality relating the LHS to $\zeta(2)$ not being directly helpful.  If someone could produce a computation showing that the difference was at most $0.074\dots$ that would indeed solve the problem, which was the point of my comment.

Comment: By the way, I thoroughly enjoyed this problem — thanks! It's not often you get to care (as I had to in my answer below) about seven hundredths of a percent. I spend more of my time doing back-of-the-envelope stuff where if you're within a factor of two, you're more than accurate enough.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, @RyanReich's estimate comes from $\frac{\pi^2}6 = \prod_p (1 + \frac1{p^2-1})$; but $\log (1 + \frac1{p^2-1}) = \frac1{p^2-1} + o(p^{-2}) \approx \frac1{p^2}$.  In particular, $\log(1 + x) < x$ for $x>0$, and so we can immediately conclude $\exp( \sum \frac1{p^2-1}) > \frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: @Theo Actually, that's not quite it (or at least, it's written differently).  I'll add an "answer" with the details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought I saw an answer here using the prime zeta function, which looked correct, so I didn't develop my answer.  But as there are requests in the comments, here it is:

We start with Aaron's suggestion in the comments:

$$\exp\left( \sum_p \frac1{p^2}\right) = \prod_p \exp\left( \frac1{p^2}\right) > \prod_p \left( 1 + \frac1{p^2} \right) = \prod_p \left( \left(1 - \frac1{p^4}\right)\sum_n \frac1{p^{2n}}\right) = \left( \prod_p \sum_n \frac1{p^{2n}} \right) \prod_p \left(1 - \frac1{p^4} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}6 \prod_p \left( \sum_n \frac1{p^{4n}} \right)^{-1} = \frac{\pi^2}6 \frac{90}{\pi^4} = \frac{15}{\pi^2} $$

Throughout $p$ ranges over primes and $n$ ranges over nonnegative integers.  I used the usual sum-to-product formula $\zeta(s) = \sum_n \frac1{n^s} = \prod_p \left( \sum_n \frac1{p^{ns}}\right)$, which follows from (and is equivalent to) unique factorization (and I think is due to Euler).  I also used known zeta values $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}6$ and $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$.  (I don't know a quick proof of the second of these; the first follows from two expansions of $\iint_0^1 \frac{\mathrm d x\, \mathrm d y}{1 + xy}$, if my memory is correct, and is in *Proofs from the Book* regardless.)

Unfortunately, estimating $\frac{15}{\pi^2}$ gives an answer that's a little less than $\frac{\pi}2$, but we'd win if we could make up a factor of $(\frac\pi 2 - \frac{15}{\pi^2}) / (\frac{15}{\pi^2}) < 3.36\%$.  So let's see if we can squeeze a little bit more out.  In the comments asatzhh suggests looking at explicit values for small $p$.  We have:
$$ \frac{\exp(\frac14)}{1 + \frac14} > 1.0272,\ \frac{\exp(\frac19)}{1 + \frac19} > 1.0057, \ \frac{\exp(\frac1{25})}{1 + \frac1{25}} > 1.0007 $$
which you can get, e.g. from Taylor expansion.

Thus our estimate above is an underestimate by at least $2.72\% + .57\% + .07\% = 3.38\%$.  This completes the proof.

I should admit, I've been getting the decimal expansions from a calculator, and rounding in whichever direction makes the estimate worse.  So I don't know how far out you need to look in Taylor expansion to get them by hand.  But the Taylor expansion of $\exp(x)$ converges very quickly, and it's easy to estimate its error.  And $\pi$ has many famous series expansions; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80.

Comment: The full infinite sum is known to great precision, http://oeis.org/A085548 . The closest thing from the ISC was 1000000/2211179, in any case about 0.45224742 http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc

Comment: (+1) for your answer. And it was my answer that used Prime Zeta Function and it wasn't correct, so I retracted it before it got any undeserved attention -_-; *sheepish grin*

Comment: @TenaliRaman, Ah, sorry.  Can I ask what was the error?  Does the Mobius function change sign too often or something?

Comment: (+1) I'm happy to see that my idea could be salvaged.  I'm curious if there is another solution that doesn't require getting an estimate and then fixing it.  And more importantly, I'm curious if there is a solution which can be done without the aid of a calculator.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I was bounding the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \ln(\zeta(2k))$ below with just the first term in the series. The first term gives $\ln(\pi^2/6)$ which as observed in the comments is slightly larger the final sum and hence the bound as used clearly isn't true. Maybe there is a way to salvage it yet by considering few more terms from the series and showing that it does bound the series below, but my math-fu skill are lacking for that :-).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is quite similar to TenaliRaman's and contains the details of my comments to the question.  The basic idea is that the "prime zeta function" is comparable to the logarithm of the actual zeta function, via the Euler product:

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n > 0} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{\text{$p$ prime}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}.$$

If we take the logarithm, we get (with some necessary analysis to prove that the homomorphism property applies to the infinite product in this case):

$$\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p \log \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}
  = \sum_p \sum_{n > 0} \frac{(p^{-s})^n}{n}.$$

The last equality is just a well-known power series for $\log (1 - x)$:

$$\log (1 - x) = -\sum_{n > 0} \frac{x^n}{n}.$$

Anyway, taking *just* the first term of the $n$ sum in the previous equation for each $p$, we get

$$\log \zeta(s) > \sum_p p^{-s}.$$

Taking $s = 2$ gives the statement of the problem, and using the known value $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$, we have

$$\sum_p p^{-2} < \log \frac{\pi^2}{6} \iff \exp \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} < \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

The right-hand side is greater than $\pi/2$, so this inequality is *consistent* with the problem, but without a proof that the difference between the two sides of the inequality above is less than $\pi^2/6 - \pi/2$, it doesn't actually finish it.

Comment: By the way, my point in the comments was that the approximation $\exp \sum_p \frac1{p^2} \approx \frac{\pi^2}6$ is pretty close.  You proved that it's $<$, whereas my comment gave $\exp \sum_p \frac1{p^2-1} > \frac{\pi^2}6$.  In principal, this might let us complete this proof.  Can we bound $\exp \sum_p \left( \frac1{p^2-1} - \frac1{p^2}\right) = \exp \sum_p \frac1{p^2(p^2-1)}$ to less than $\frac{\pi}6(\pi-3)$?  Probably not...

Answer (score 1):

An early attempt which is clearly wrong. Making this into a community wiki, in case someone wants to take a stab at it and see if something can be salvaged here.

===============================================

The exponent is called as the Prime Zeta Function. From Mathworld [1], 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}  \ln(\zeta(2k))$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $\zeta(n)$ is the Riemann zeta function. Therefore,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^2} > \frac{\mu(1)}{1}  \ln(\zeta(2)) = \ln\left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} \right)$$
$$\exp\left( \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^2} \right) > \frac{\pi^2}{6} > \frac{3\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

[1] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html

Comment: Your last inequality is false, and further more even if it was true, the mobius function changes sign infinitely often so you would still have to prove that the terms don't cancel out part of the first term (which they do).

Comment: Yes, realized that a while ago. Proving things without sleep is a bad idea.